# Accumulo - Adding collection of mutations to batchwriter that exceeds buffer limit

Tags: java, collections, buffer, accumulo

What happens when you add a collection of Mutations to a BatchWriter whose overall size exceeds the set buffer? Does the BatchWriter just say okay, I'll process what I am set to then get to the rest afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Accumulo BatchWriter will auto-flush its current batch when its buffer gets full. The [API](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.5/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/BatchWriter.html) also allows you to add Mutations with an Iterable. This is not the same as adding a collection. When you use this, you're not adding the whole collection at once. Instead, what you're really doing is providing a source feed of Mutations to be added to the current batch one at a time. It may be that the batch will be flushed before the entire collection has completed its iteration.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Forgot that I was adding iterables XD Thank you for setting me straight. Much thanks.